# Suppose that the $\lim_{x\rightarrow c}{|f(x)|}$ exists. Give an example to show that $\lim_{x\rightarrow c}{f(x)}$ may not exist.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions, absolute-value

Suppose that the $\lim_{x\rightarrow c}{|f(x)|}$ exists. Give an example to show that $\lim_{x\rightarrow c}{f(x)}$ may not exist.

I had done a similar problem using sequences rather than using functions where {$x_n$} = (-1)$^n$ was the correct sequence, but since that is not a function. I can not use the same idea for this problem.

Should I try to solve this using the Delta-Epsilon Definition or is there something else I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something rather similar to your idea (which worked for sequences).
Take $f$ defined on $\mathbb{R}$ by $$f(x) = \begin{cases}
1& \text{ if } x\in\mathbb{Q}\\
-1& \text{ if } x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}
\end{cases}$$
$\lvert f\rvert$ is constant, equal to $1$; so continuous everywhere, But $f$ is discontinuous everywhere.$^{(\dagger)}$

*Note that you can replace $\mathbb{Q}$ by any set $A$ dense in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\mathbb{R}\setminus A$ is dense as well.*

$(\dagger)$ Indeed, for any $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and any $\delta>0$, the interval $(a-\delta, a+\delta)$ contains both rationals and irrationals, so $f$ will take both value $1$ and $-1$ in $(a-\delta, a+\delta)$. Now, take e.g. $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{2}$ to contradict continuity at $a$.

Answer (score 0):

> I had done a similar problem using sequences rather than using functions where {$x_n$} = (-1)$^n$ was the correct sequence, but since that is not a function. I can not use the same idea for this problem.

This trick divides the natural numbers into the *even* and *odd* numbers, producing the desired oscillating behavior, no longer present after taking the absolute value.

**Hint**: can you divide the real numbers into two subsets, again mapping $f$ to $\pm 1$ depending on the subset $x$ is in, to obtain a similar effect?

$$f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} : x \mapsto \left\{ \begin{array}{rl} 1 & \quad x \in A \\ -1 & \quad x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus A  \end{array}\right.$$

Answer (score 0):

Define
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
x+1 & \text{if $-1\le x<0$} \\[4px]
x-1 & \text{if $0<x\le 1$}
\end{cases}
$$
and consider the limits of $f(x)$ and $|f(x)|$ at $0$:
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0^-}f(x)&=\\
\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)&=\\
\lim_{x\to0}|f(x)|&=
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Take $f(x):=\operatorname{sign}(\cos(\frac{1}{x}))$ for $x>0$ and $f(x)=1$ otherwise. For $x_n:=\frac{1}{n\pi}$ you get $\operatorname{sign}(\cos(x_n))=(-1)^{n+1}$, which doesn't converge, but $|f(x)|=1$ for all $x$ and thus the limit exists in this case.

Comment: If you presume continuity of $f$ then $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)$ is guaranteed to exist and be equal to $f(c)$ by the definition of continuity. That follows without reference to the hypothesis $\lim_{x\to c}|f(x)|$ exists.

Comment: Youre right, I just had a moment aberration... thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Intuition: the absolute value does away with distinctions in sign. So in our search for counterexamples, we should look for functions where a sign difference breaks continuity, but the absolute value is continuous.

So how about the sign function,
$$f(x) = \operatorname{sgn}(x) = \begin{cases} 1, & x \geq 0 \\ -1, & x < 0 \end{cases}$$
with $c=0$? We have $\lim_{x\to 0}|f(x)| = \lim_{x\to 0}1 = 1$ but $\lim_{x\to 0^-} f(x) = -1$ and $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x) = 1$, so $f$ is not continuous at $0$.